# Append Each Element In Two Second Intervals

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a variable that contains HTML code of a bunch of items. I would like to append all these items in two second intervals. The code I have written below appends all of the items at once. I do not understand why it is doing this as the `setTimeout()` is within the `each()`.

```
var myVar = "<div class='item'>Item01</div>" +
            "<div class='item'>Item02</div>" +
            "<div class='item'>Item03</div>";

$(myVar).each( function() {
    var value = $(this);
    setTimeout( function {
        $('.item-list').append(value);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: `each` is not going to wait for the `setTimeout` as it continues looping over the elements so it will loop through the elements in just a few milliseconds, and a `setTimeout' will be called for each element with almost no delay between them

Comment: It looks like you have one variable holding all the elements and you append the variable, so it adds all 3 elements at the same time. Maybe you have to make an array of strings and add them one at a time.

Comment: I was all proud of myself to point out that a single string (even with 3 `<div>` elements was still a single string and $.each() could "know", and once again [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/) proves that he is smarter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myVar = "<div class='item'>Item01</div>" +
            "<div class='item'>Item02</div>" +
            "<div class='item'>Item03</div>";

$(myVar).each( function(index) {
    var value = $(this);
    setTimeout( function() {
        $('.item-list').append(value);
    }, 2000 * (index + 1));
};
```

### Explanation

In your original code, the loop occurs very quickly. Let's pretend each iteration of the loop takes 1ms. That means that the first item is added 2001ms later, the second item 2002ms later, and the third one 2003ms later.

By getting the index of the item in the array, we can add the first item 2000ms later, the second one 4000ms later, and so on.

#### Update: Fixed syntax error.

Comment: wait is jQuery.each() really that smart to take 3 divs in a string and treat them like different elements in an array?

Comment: typo carried over from OP code...missing `()` in `setTimeout` but this solution works great  http://jsfiddle.net/CJTk2/

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. I guess I misunderstood how `setTimeout()` works in this case. I tried your code, but I did not see my items getting appended. http://jsfiddle.net/bJZTm/1/

Comment: I added the `()` in my fiddle, but I still could not get it to work. Can you link your fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/bJZTm/4/

Comment: @charlietfl Where is your post... I don't see it.

Comment: @JasonSperske It's not `jQuery.each` that's smart, it is `jQuery` (i.e. `$(string)`) that's smart.